# Sorted a list of tuple and return first element of tuple in python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to sort a list of tuple and only return first element of tuple I have following code but it is possible to merge 2nd and 3rd (two rtn statement) into one-liner list comprehensive? I see lots of duplicated post about sort a list of tuple but I do not see any example to only return first element of tuple. Please advise

```
    ch_map = {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 7, 'd': 2}
    rtn = sorted([(k, c) for k, c in ch_map.items()], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    rtn = [i[0] for i in rtn]
    #['c', 'b', 'd', 'a'] expected result
```

Comment: `sorted(ch_map, key=ch_map.get)` nicely structured question, also a duplicate.

Comment: good call. thank you. please help me to close it since it is duplicated